# Search string by means of StreamReader

Tags: c#

I have this code in C # perform a string search from a .txt file, but it shows only one line.

and I need that 3 from the first match.

Example: Search: 1

result

line 1

line 2

line 3

Help me please. regards
.......................................

Text File

---

Code: 1

Note name: Josh

body Note : tex

---

Code: 2

Note name: Josh

body note: txt

---

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Test 
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
    enter code here
    try 
    {
      string searchString = "some string";
      searchString = Console.ReadLine();
      // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
      // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
      {
        string line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
        // the file is reached.
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
          if(line.Contains(searchString))
          {
            // Do some logic (the search string is found)
              //   I need to show 3 lines here
              //    Code:1
              //   Note name: Josh
              //   Body Note : tex
              // for the moment Console.WriteLine(line);just shows me 1               

                  Console.WriteLine(line);
                  count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      // Let the user know what went wrong.
      Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can they search just the number or any string in the file?

Comment: find the first line
"Note name: Josh"

but I need the WriteLine to show at least 3 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one line is becuase your keep comparing the `searchString` with each line in the file once a match was found. You could add a flag to bypass the `contains` like:

```
bool found = false;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
{
    string line;
    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
    // the file is reached.
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        // bypass the search once we've found a match
        if(found || line.Contains(searchString))
        {
            // Do some logic (the search string is found)
            //   I need to show 3 lines here
            //    Code:1
            //   Note name: Josh
            //   Body Note : tex
            // for the moment Console.WriteLine(line);just shows me 1               
            found = true;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            count++;
            if(count == 3) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could read the `stream` all the way to its end and then check and post-process:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    string contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    if (contents.Contains(searchString))
    {
        // do you magic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brother I worked perfectly. thanks for your help

Comment: @BryanBWeiss you bet. Glad I could help.